# unabel to call API using volley lib with error NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-volley

**import com.android.volley.Response
has problem
Unused import directive**

**recyclerView work's fine
i think problem is in MainActivity using volley lib**

**Main_Activity

```
`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), newItemClicked {
    private lateinit var mAdapter:News_Adapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     val re = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        re.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
         fetchdata()
        mAdapter= News_Adapter(this)
        re.adapter = mAdapter
    }
    private fun fetchdata() {
        val url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=6c0cb81d850c49c0a8cfafc5457c8836"
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            null,
            {
                val newsJasonArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
                val newsArray = ArrayList<News>()
                for(i in 0 until newsJasonArray.length()){
                    val newsJasonObject = newsJasonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val news = News(
                        newsJasonObject.getString("title"),
                        newsJasonObject.getString("author"),
                        newsJasonObject.getString("url"),
                        newsJasonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                    )
                newsArray.add(news)
                }
                mAdapter.updateNews(newsArray)
            },
            {
                //
            }
        )

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
    }



    override fun onItemClicked(item: News) {
       // Toast.makeText(this, item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val builder =  CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
        val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(item.url))
    }

}`
```

**News Adapter

```
`class News_Adapter (private val listener : newItemClicked): RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsViewHolder>() {

      private val items:ArrayList<News> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsViewHolder {

        val View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_news,parent,false)
        val vviewholder = NewsViewHolder(View)
        View.setOnClickListener{
                listener.onItemClicked(items[vviewholder.adapterPosition])
        }

        return vviewholder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = items[position]
        holder.textView.text = currentItem.title
        holder.author.text = currentItem.author
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(currentItem.urlToImage).into(holder.image)

    }
    fun updateNews(updatednews:ArrayList<News>){
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(updatednews)

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
class NewsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
     val textView :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    val image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)
    val author: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author)
}
interface newItemClicked{
    fun onItemClicked(item:News)
}
```

**ERROR

> E/OpenGLRenderer: fbcNotifyFrameComplete error: undefined symbol:fbcNotifyFrameComplete

> E/OpenGLRenderer: fbcNotifyNoRender error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyNoRender

> E/BLASTBufferQueue: ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0 isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=1, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4,currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2

> E/BLASTBufferQueue: ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0 isEGL=1,mPendingRelease.size()=2, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4,
> currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2

> E/Volley: [37] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected
> response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=6c0cb81d850c49c0a8cfafc5457c8836

> E/Volley: [37] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected
> response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=6c0cb81d850c49c0a8cfafc5457c8836